# UploadedFile Junit Primefaces

Tags: junit, primefaces

Is there are any way to instantiate an object of UploadedFile without using Mockito?

I've been searching but I only have found examples using Mockito. I'm trying to do Junits and I would like to avoid using it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is an interface, so if you don't want to use Mockito (or a similar mocking tool) just create your own class and implement the interface explicitly. There are not that many methods, so it is straightforward.

EDIT: or just use the public constructor in [DefaultUploadedFile](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/model/DefaultUploadedFile.html#DefaultUploadedFile--) and go with that implementation.